# How to compute the probability that a poisoned transaction has reached the exchange by random chance in EAE attack?

Tags: attack

When there is an EAE attack, how to compute the probability that a poisoned transaction has reached the exchange by random chance? Additionally, how to compute the probability that n poisoned transactions has reached the exchange by random chance? Then, how to compute the statistical significance of these results?

Further information on EAE attack: https://youtu.be/iABIcsDJKyM